# Layout: How to correctly set rubber block width

Tags: html, css

Now I'm making a legend for the chart.

---

There is a specific layout that needs to be matched.
**[rect with color] [Legend item name] [Legend item value]**
The legend width is a **constant**.

Title max-width = 105px, If the text width is longer, then it should be added **'...'** and then everything should fit in one line. But the Legend item value ​​can be any (for example  10, 1000000, 23123421442 and so on) And with a large number of digits in the number, the title is transferred to a new line.

I'm trying to find a way to automatically reduce the title width (with the addition of '...' )so that for any large values, the text will still be on one line.

I have attached a sample code for a better understanding of the problem.
Сan this be done in pure css? Thanks !

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 200px;
}

.left-item {
    flex-grow: 1;
    min-width: 0;
}

.right-item {
    margin-left: auto;
}

.block {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.legend-item {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    line-height: 16px;
}

.title_rect {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    min-height: 16px;
    min-width: 16px;
    margin-right: 4px;
    background: blue;
}

.title_name {
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: $gray-dark-color;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    max-width: 105px;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.legend-item_value {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: gray;
}
```

```html
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="block">
          <div class="left-item">
            <div left class="legend-item_title">
              <span class="title_rect"></span>
              <span class="title_name">Long text Long Text Long Text</span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="right-item">
            <div right class="legend-item_value">
              <span>10000000000</span>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="block">
        <div class="left-item">
          <div left class="legend-item_title">
            <span class="title_rect"></span>
            <span class="title_name">Long text Long Text Long Text</span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="right-item">
          <div right class="legend-item_value">
            <span>1000</span>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh, it turned out to be enough to add one property `display: flex;` for `.legend-item_title` and everything began to work as intended)